# VSCode import problem with windows API call

Tags: go, winapi, visual-studio-code

When importing **golang.org/x/sys/windows** in VSCode, I can only choose **SIGDescribe**, nothing else.

Hovering over the import, following errors appear.

> error while importing golang.org/x/sys/windows: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/username/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20210630005230-0f9fa26af87c/windows

> could not import golang.org/x/sys/windows (no required module provides package "golang.org/x/sys/windows")compilerBrokenImport

The manual command `go get golang.org/x/sys/windows` gives the following error message

> Command 'gopls.go_get_package' failed: Error: err: exit status 1: stderr: package golang.org/x/sys/windows: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/username/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20210630005230-0f9fa26af87c/windows .

I already re-installed Golang and updated GoTools in VSCode, no changes.

**Goal**: The following code below should work.

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

func main() {
    user32DLL := windows.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
}
```

OS: Ubuntu 21.04

GO Version: 1.16.6

Editor: VSCode 1.58.1

Comment: `gopls` still has limited support for cross-platform development. If the project builds with GOOS=windows, then it is fine.

Comment: you are right, after GOOS=windows the program compiles and works, even VSCode lintings are full of errors and go import module **windows** does not recognize methods like NewLazyDLL.

Comment: There is a gopls issue at https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29202 . You can squelch the VSCode errors by placing `//go:build windows` at the top of your .go files that are only compatible with Windows, but this also disables all code completion on current versions of gopls.

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder somewhere `something`. Then make a file `something/main.go`:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

func main() {
   println(windows.EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE == 1)
}
```

Then build:

```
go mod init something
go mod tidy
go build
```

Comment: **hover errors on import shows now**: could not import golang.org/x/sys/windows (cannot find package "golang.org/x/sys/windows" in any of /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/windows (from $GOROOT) /home/username/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/windows (from $GOPATH))compilerBrokenImport ..... further... **go build error shows now**: package something imports golang.org/x/sys/windows: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/username/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20210630005230-0f9fa26af87c/windows